# Transform GeoTiff to WMT

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, geotiff-tiff, wmts

I'm not a GIS specialist at all so this question may seem dumb to you.
I have a GeoTiff base of images (hundreds) I'd like to transform to a WMTS repository to put behind a web server. Web pages are rendered by openlayers. 
I'm looking for a way to do GeoTiff to WMTS transformation on linux if possible.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question is expected to show some degree of research on your part. Describe what you have looked into and which specific issues you're facing.

Comment: Please look after how to concatenate (mosaic) GeoTiff images to a single raster, then how to publish it via a tile server, like GeoServer's GeoWebCache, MapServer's MapCache, TileCache, MapProxy, or TileStache (I'm only 100% sure about WMTS support in GWC).